What is relationship between the Laplace transform of the ideally-sampled signal and that of the original continuous signal?
Suppose a continuous signal $x(t)$, the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ is $X(s)$. Suppose the ideally-sampled signal of $x(t)$ is $\hat{x}(t)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}\limits^{\infty}x(nT)\delta(t-nT)$, the Laplace transform of $\hat{x}(t)$ is $\hat{X}(s)$. That what is the relationship of between $X(s)$ and $\hat{X}(s)$?
I know that the Fourier transform of $\hat{x}(t)$ is the periodic extension of that of ${x}(t)$. Does the Laplace transform also follow such conclusion?

The Laplace transform $\hat{X}(s)$ of the sampled signal $\hat{x}(t)$ cannot be written in terms of the Laplace transform $X(s)$ of $x(t)$. The Laplace transform of $\hat{x}(t)$ is
\begin{align*}\hat{X}(s) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\delta(t-nT)e^{-st}dt \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)e^{-st}dt \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)e^{-snT} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)z^{-n},\qquad z=e^{sT}
\end{align*}
which is just the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the sequence $x(nT)$ with $z=e^{sT}$, assuming that the sum converges.
Note that $T\hat{X}(s)$ is the Riemann sum of $X(s)$:
$$X(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-st}dt\approx\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)e^{-snT}T=T\hat{X}(s)$$
Hence, $\hat{X}(s)$ is a scaled approximation of $X(s)$. This can be seen in the following example. Let $x(t)=u(t)$ be the unit step sequence. We have
$$X(s)=\frac{1}{s}$$
and
$$\hat{X}(s)=\left.\frac{1}{1-e^{-sT}}\right|_{T\ll 1}\approx\frac{1}{sT}=\frac{1}{T}X(s)$$

Note that $T\hat{X}(s)$ is the Riemann sum of $X(s)$:
$$\ X(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-st}dt\approx\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)e^{-snT}T=T\hat{X}(s) \$$
Hence, $\hat{X}(s)$ is a scaled approximation of $X(s)$. $$\$$ - - - - which is why I always include the $T$ in with the dirac comb sampling function.

Yes it follows the same because Laplace is nothing but making your non convergence or unstable signal to stable by ROC(Sigma) and taking Fourier transform of it. So it follows the same.
